# Spotfire: To create Slider in Text Area

Tags: spotfire

I have an date property for which I have created an document property as StartDate and EndDate, and in SQL query the same will be used to filter. In the Text Area , I am using it as Control Type: INPUT Field as this has two different values for start date and end date (as shown in fig: [image]), I need to merge this two date property into single Slider Control Type. I tried to use Functions using formula "First(DateProperty)". However I am not successful . Can someone help me on this?

Comment: I also tried creating a function with expression "First (DateProperty)" and "Last (DateProperty)". However I m getting below error:  "Automatic updates cannot be performed due to cyclic dependencies"Cycle found:
Property: ${enddate}
Data On Demand
Data Column: [TableName].[DateProperty Column]
Data Function: DateRange
Property: ${startdate}

Comment: I don't think this is possible from what I've seen, but i could be wrong.

Comment: I just found the reason for the issue as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the reason for the issue as well, below are two points. i May be wrong as well:

1) To create an slider calendar, we need to create a function. This function will show the data tables which are of from different connections and In our analysis we have single connection and table for Each components .Due to this we are getting error called Cyclic Dependencies and Function is not working.
2) Next to create a simple table having only date property also causing problem as even this should be an Imported table and not linked to the external databases.